Conectar Linux a MS SQLServer usando ODBC Y FreeTDS
Tengo hosting con linux el cual he intentado conectar a sql server de todas las maneras que he encontrado en sitios y no logro que se realice la conexión.
Tengo creado el archivo odbcinst.ini y el .odbc.ini. También esta activa la extensión PDO_ODBC para php.
odbcinst.ini
[FreeTDS] 
Description = ODBC for FreeTDS 
Driver = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so 
Setup = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so.2 
Driver64 = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so 
Setup64 = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so.2 
FileUsage = 1

.odbc.ini
[mssql_odbc]
Driver=FreeTDS
Description=MSSQL Server
Database=database
Server=server.name
Port=1433

en php recibo este error:  SQLSTATE[08001] SQLConnect: 0 [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
en la consola usando isql o iusql:  isql -v mssql_odbc username pwd
[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Adaptive Server connection failed
[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Adaptive Server connection failed

linea de conexion en php usando odbc_connect
$dsn = "mssql_odbc"; 
$username = "user";  
$password = "pwd";  

$connection = odbc_connect($dsn, $username, $password);

Usando new PDO
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda u orientación
